# i want to upload in chrome

Tags: selenium, file-upload

I want to upload an excel file using chrome :

```
driver.findElement(By.XPATH('//*[@id="main-menu"]/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a/span'))
fileInput.sendKeys("C://path//file.xlsx")



"button">Browse File</button>
                                      -1.amazonaws.com/cloud.alerts/uploads/sample/sample_custom_smsfile.xlsx" style="padding: 6px 10px !important; ">Download Sample File
```

Comment: what is fileInput ? Is it a webElement ? Share your HTML code in proper format. Note that sendKeys will only work if input type is file/

Comment: </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="margin-tb-15">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success text-capitalize" id="ac-btn-imprt" type="button">Browse File</button>
                                            <a class="text-primary download-sample" href="//s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloud.alerts/uploads/sample/sample_custom_smsfile.xlsx" style="padding: 6px 10px !important; ">Download Sample File

Comment: What if the input type is not file?in my case type is button.